# How can I fix this error about loading .wav assets in MonoGame 3.2?

Tags: monogame

I'm trying to add a music file to my project, but I get the error "Could not load EpicScores.wav asset!"

I load the music file like this:

```
Song sound1 = Content.Load<Song>(@"EpicScoreCreatorOfWorlds.wav");
```

I've tried both with and without the `.wav` ending.

My file is added to the *Content* folder, and I've made sure my file properties are set to the "Content" build action and to "copy always."

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Don't pass the extension.

Comment: Still dont work, same error.

Comment: http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/457268

Looks like you may have to edit some MonoGame source to get it to work.

Comment: How is it possible to edit the source?

Comment: The code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame) but it sounds like you actually *don't* want to implement the "fix" since it's incorrect per one of the maintainers; if you do it you will create a divergence in your local version that will never be resolved upstream, causing headache for you later.

Answer (score 2):

Per [this thread on the MonoGame forums](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/457268), this appears to the result of a legacy MonoGame feature that allowed the loading of unprocessed `.wav` files via the content pipeline API without *actually* using the content pipeline.

You should [leverage the content pipeline](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing) to load your assets (the content pipeline will transform your assets from their source format to a more suitable runtime format; that's why you don't need the file extension in the load call, because you're actually loading a different kind of file than you'd think).

This involves creating a content project for your content, adding the music asset and setting the content processor for it (as you've previously set the build actions; you probably want `MonoGame Song` in this case).

Comment: Yeah, I see. But the problem is getting Content Pipeline to work on VS2013, yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jaquadro.com/2013/11/migrating-monogame-projects-to-vs2013-and-windows-8-1/

I found out how I can get Content Pipeline to work for Visual Studio 2013, in the above link.

Comment: You should add more to your answer, such as the steps you took. Link die over time. You should then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct you cannot load .wav files as 'song'. wav files may only be used as 'Sound Effects' .you can convert the file to .wma and then use it.U also have to create .xnb file.
For a song to play on windows 8/windows phone ,u have to copy both the wma file and xnb file to the content folder.

Here is a solution that i created by modifying 'Xnacontentcompiler' which is an opensource project.

http://1drv.ms/1drPvzv

run xnacontentcompiler(assuming you have xna4.0).
use the format converter to convert file to wma and then create xnb file for that wma. 
now copy both the xnb and wma to your content folder,change property to content and copy always and load the file like you normally do.